# Is there a way I can have two instances of an object with the same name and use one or another?

Tags: java, object, if-statement

I'm a beginner and I'm stuck with this.
The thing is that I'm doing kind of a game (text game)[image]

I made and if statement which lets the player choose whether they wanna be a warrior or a mage, the thing is that I don't wanna create both at the same time, so only want one to be created at a time with the name "player", the problem is that it gives me an error and I doesn't work as I've imagined it to work.
I know I can just create them with different names but then when the player attacks or gets attacked the name for that is "player" and I think making if statements every time I wanna it to attack with different names wouldn't be so efficient.

[image]

Comment: Please update code instead https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead [edit] your question to include your code as text (with proper code formatting) instead. Also, whenever you mention "an error", please post the *exact message* that you get.

Comment: Use inheritance, an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of new Mage() or new Warrior() as you are doing you can try to create a higher level class.

For example, you can do new playerClass(Mage).

Also I suggest you to use enum for the classes.